Not able to set module name in Terragrunt config
I have a multi-environment infrastructure in Terragrunt where I want to deploy multiple instances of a module "resource-group" up to this Point the configuration is identical besides later mentioned sections.
When I come to deploy said infrastucture using terragrunt run-all apply it is replacing the resource group in nonprod-zone1 with prod-zone1 and prod-zone1 with nonprod-zone1 depending on which resource is currently standing.
This hints together with the logs(1) at a namespace collision, where each resource in the modules is not seperately namespaced by the module from the rest.
How would I fix this (i.e. by naming the modules instead of just specifying terraform/sources).
Is it possible to deploy the same module multiple times?
This Problem might be fixed by deploying from the zone directory (i.e. nonprod/zone), but the same issue would occur ultimately when one tries to deploy multiple modules within a zone using said procedure. the like would have to be done if multiple vnets or similar were to be deployed from within there.
The terragrunt.hcl in nonprod/zone1/resource-group/terragrunt.hcl and the prod analogue Looks as follows:
 
# nonprod/zone1/resource-group/terragrunt.hcl
 
locals {
 
    module_url  = "gitserverurl.tld/module"
    zone        = "zone1"   # or "zone2"
    environment = "nonprod" # or "prod" accordingly
 
}
 
inputs {
    resource_group_name = "project-${local.zone}-${local.environment}"
 
}
 
terraform {
    source = "tfr://${local.module_url}"
}
 

The module code looks as follows
# main.tf
 
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    name     = var.resource_group_name
    location = "eu-west"
 
}
 
# variables.tf
 
variable "resource_group_name" {
    description = "the name of the created resource group"
}
 

The File Structure is similar to this:
/
    nonprod/
        zone1/
            resource-group/
                terragrunt.hcl
        zone2/
            ...
    prod/
        zone1/
            resource-group/
                terragrunt.hcl
        zone2/
            ...
    terragrunt.hcl

Logs:
# azurerm_resource_group.rg must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
~ id = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/project-zone1-prod" -> (known after apply)
~ name = "project-zone1-prod" -> "project-zone1-nonprod" # forces replacement
}
# (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
}
Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
Changes to Outputs:
~ rg_resource_group_id = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/project-zone1-prod" -> (known after apply)
~ rg_resource_group_name = "project-zone1-prod" -> "project-zone1-nonprod"
 

Expected:
Deploy the infrastructure and get multiple instances.
Got:
Terraform replaces the instances, so that only one stands.


Set module name in Terragrunt config

The issue you're facing replacing the name can be overcome by each module instance has a unique identifier. We can use dependency in terragurnt to generate unique names.
We can deploy the sample ensuring each instance is uniquely identified by making the necessary changes in the way I mentioned below
terragrunt.hcl
terraform {
  source = "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/modules/resource-group"
}

inputs = {
  common_var = "common_value"
}

modules/resourcegroup/main.tf:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    
  }
}

variable "resource_group_name" {}
variable "location" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

nonprod/zone1/resource-group/terragrunt.hcl:
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

locals {
  environment = "nonprod"
  zone        = "zone1"
}

terraform {
  source = "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/../../../modules/resource-group"
}

inputs = {
  resource_group_name = "project-${local.zone}-${local.environment}-1"
  location            = "West Europe"
}

prod/zone1/resource-group/terragrunt.hcl:
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

locals {
  environment = "prod"
  zone        = "zone1"
}

terraform {
  source = "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/../../../modules/resource-group"
}

inputs = {
  resource_group_name = "project-${local.zone}-${local.environment}-1"
  location            = "West Europe"
}

continue with rest of the configuration for other zone with unique names.
Deployment:
now run the command  terragrunt run-all files

now move select the mentioned directroy cd project-root/nonprod/zone1/resource-group
now run the terragrunt apply
This configuration helps you with constraint mentioned in the query
Refer:
azurerm_resource_group | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/locals/


The issue you're facing replacing the name can be overcome by each module instance has a unique identifier. We can use dependency in terragurnt to generate unique names.

Where do I need to put the dependency?

ou should put the dependency block in your environment-specific terragrunt.hcl files to generate unique names for each module instance.
it looks something like this
dependency "common" {
config_path = "../../.."
}

which path would i need to include?
